# How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time values for the installation process. Is there a way to add text labels whose are marked in the below screenshot ?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was not that easy to implement this feature before the [`CurInstallProgressChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurInstallProgressChanged) event method was introduced in Inno Setup 5.5.4. But now, having this event available, you can write a script like this:

Special thanks to [user1662035](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1662035/user1662035) for the proposed idea for the fix of hiding labels at rollback process.

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
function GetTickCount: DWORD;
  external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  StartTick: DWORD;
  PercentLabel: TNewStaticText;
  ElapsedLabel: TNewStaticText;
  RemainingLabel: TNewStaticText;

function TicksToStr(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;
  Result := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  PercentLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  PercentLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  PercentLabel.Left := 0;
  PercentLabel.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top +
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height + 12;

  ElapsedLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  ElapsedLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  ElapsedLabel.Left := 0;
  ElapsedLabel.Top := PercentLabel.Top + PercentLabel.Height + 4;

  RemainingLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  RemainingLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  RemainingLabel.Left := 0;
  RemainingLabel.Top := ElapsedLabel.Top + ElapsedLabel.Height + 4;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
    StartTick := GetTickCount;
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
    Cancel := False;
    if ExitSetupMsgBox then
    begin
      Cancel := True;
      Confirm := False;
      PercentLabel.Visible := False;
      ElapsedLabel.Visible := False;
      RemainingLabel.Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
var
  CurTick: DWORD;
begin
  CurTick := GetTickCount;
  PercentLabel.Caption :=
    Format('Done: %.2f %%', [(CurProgress * 100.0) / MaxProgress]);
  ElapsedLabel.Caption := 
    Format('Elapsed: %s', [TicksToStr(CurTick - StartTick)]);
  if CurProgress > 0 then
  begin
    RemainingLabel.Caption :=
      Format('Remaining: %s', [TicksToStr(
        ((CurTick - StartTick) / CurProgress) * (MaxProgress - CurProgress))]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @user1662035, yes, that was the immediate thought I had. But I'll try to look at something more precise yet. Anyway, you might use the ready made [`ExitSetupMsgBox`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exitsetupmsgbox) function to show the exit confirmation dialog. However, isn't that message different from "*Do you want to exit setup ?*". I don't have Inno Setup by hand at this time to check...

Comment: As of now, one can use built-in [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback) instead of using external `WrapTimerProc` from `InnoCallback.dll`. For an example see [Inno Setup - How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress at uninstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41698725/850848).