# Progress bar with Total, File, time, etc

Tags: inno-setup

Can anyone tell me how to put in my exe the progress with
Total progress: X MB of Y MB
File:
Speed:
Status:
Elapsed time:
Remaining time:

and the button "Hide"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported in Inno Setup.

But the sources are available (Inno is open source) so you can modify them and add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use CurInstallProgressChanged function.

You can see this post for some "inspiration": [How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092779/how-to-show-percent-done-elapsed-time-and-estimated-time-progress)