# Creating new progress bar and customizing Installer page in innosetup

Tags: progress-bar, inno-setup, pascalscript

**I want to create a new progress bar and customize the installer page a bit.
Here is what I want in the installing page:**

- A new progress bar that will show Current file Status(Percentage complete).
- The default progress bar will show overall progress(Percentage complete)
- There will be 2 percentage complete label,one for the overall progress,another for current file progress,They will situated in top of each Progress bar.

Comment: There is no way to get percentage of a single file installation. The rest you can [`find here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20092779/960757), just modify the positions.

Comment: @ Tlama do you know how to change the caption "Extraction files..." .

Comment: @ Tlama do you know how to change the caption "Extraction files..." .Please tell me.

Comment: I don't know what is that. There are [`these labels`](http://i.imgur.com/AgUAimL.png) on the `wpInstalling`, maybe some of them shows something like that...

Comment: @Tlama Yeah i want change that in `wpinstaling` page.What I should do?

Comment: If you want to change that particular message *Extracting files...* to some other text, you can override it in the `[Messages]` section where you alter the `StatusExtractFiles` message (check the help for that section). Just note, that this message is shown just for a short time, only when the files are being copied.

Comment: @Tlama Thanks for giving me the idea.It working well.