# How to change size and style of a caption in inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup, percentage, pascalscript

I have the [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092779/how-to-show-percent-done-elapsed-time-and-estimated-time-progress) (answered by TLama).
I made some changes in the script,Now I want the caption will look like the following image :

[image]

Is it possible to change the size and style(bold) the caption 
`Completed`(I change it from caption `Done`).
How to do the changes in the caption in inno setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Change the label's `Font.Style` to `[fsBold]` to make it bold. To modify its size change the `Font.Size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fully modified code :

```
[Code]
function GetTickCount: DWORD;
  external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  StartTick: DWORD;
  PercentLabel: TNewStaticText;
  ElapsedLabel: TNewStaticText;
  RemainingLabel: TNewStaticText;

function TicksToStr(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;
  Result := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  PercentLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  PercentLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  PercentLabel.Left := 110;
    PercentLabel.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top +
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height + 50;
  PercentLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold]
  PercentLabel.Font.Size := 14

  ElapsedLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  ElapsedLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  ElapsedLabel.Left := 0;
  ElapsedLabel.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top +
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height + 12;
  ElapsedLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold]

  RemainingLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  RemainingLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  RemainingLabel.Left := 270;
  RemainingLabel.Top := ElapsedLabel.Top;
  RemainingLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold]

end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
    StartTick := GetTickCount;
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
    Cancel := False;
    if ExitSetupMsgBox then
    begin
      Cancel := True;
      Confirm := False;
      PercentLabel.Visible := False;
      ElapsedLabel.Visible := False;
      RemainingLabel.Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```