# How to specify the period during which the remaining-time-label is updated in Inno Setup?

Tags: time, inno-setup, pascalscript

I wanted to show remaining time during an installation like in the following question and used the code from there, posted by TLama: [How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092779/how-to-show-percent-done-elapsed-time-and-estimated-time-progress)

The code is working for me, so thanks for this.
But if you install bigger files, the period in which the "remaining-time-label" is updated, is too fast.

So I wanted to ask, how to change the update period of the "remaining-time-label", so that it updates only every second or every half second.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GetTickCount` to remember the last update time. On the next calls to `CurInstallProgressChanged` calculate difference to `CurTick` and update the labels only if the difference is large enough (1000 = 1 second)

```pascal
var
  LastUpdate: DWORD;

procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
var
  CurTick: DWORD;
begin
  CurTick := GetTickCount;
  if (CurTick - LastUpdate) >= 1000 then
  begin
    LastUpdate := CurTick;
    // Update labels
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works for me. Didn't expect it to be that easy, feeling really silly now...