# Inno Setup - How to format time span in words (seconds, minutes, hours)

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using the code [How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092779/how-to-show-percent-done-elapsed-time-and-estimated-time-progress)

I would like to replace the numbers by "seconds", "minutes" and "hours", that is, instead of "0:01:37", I would like to display: "1 minute 37 seconds". Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean that instead of times like "3:20:15" you want to show "3 hours, 20 minutes and 15 seconds"? Or just "3 hours" and only later when the time is like "0:20:15", you will want to display "20 minutes"?

Comment: If possible, I would like to replace the numbers by seconds, minutes and hours, that is, instead of 0:01:37, I would like to display: 1 minute 37 seconds.

Comment: So what's stopping you? Change the last line to display whatever you want; you have the values and the format string. Alter the format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit smarter implementation that skips zeros and handles plural:

```pascal
procedure AddTime(var S: string; Count: Integer; L: string);
begin
  if Count > 0 then
  begin
    if S <> '' then
    begin
      S := S + ' ';
    end;
    if Count > 1 then L := L + 's';
    S := S + Format('%d %s', [Count, L]);
  end;
end;

function TicksToStr(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;

  AddTime(Result, Hours, 'hour');
  AddTime(Result, Minutes, 'minute');
  AddTime(Result, Seconds, 'second');
  if Result = '' then Result := '-'; { no time }
end;
```

Comment: What is not displayed correctly? Please learn to describe your problem! Is it about 0 seconds remaining?

Comment: I've edited my answer already - Replace the `'-'` with whatever you want to display for zero.

Comment: Another question, Is it possible to reduce or adjust the time so that the zero does not extend as much? That is, I see that time zero is maintained for a long time (Sorry for my bad english).

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question. Anyway, I do not think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the format string being provided for `Format` to whatever you want to display.

```
function TicksToStr(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;
  Result := Format('%.2d hours, %.2d minutes, %.2d seconds', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite!!