# Inno Setup - How to reduce or adjust the time so that the zero does not extend as much?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using the code [How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092779/how-to-show-percent-done-elapsed-time-and-estimated-time-progress). Is it possible to reduce or adjust the time so that the zero does not extend as much? That is, I see that time zero is maintained for a long time (Sorry for my bad english).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's generally unpredictable, how long installation tasks will last. That's why Inno Setup cannot assess that correctly itself.

You would have to came up with smarter algorithm than Inno Setup authors. And even if you find such algorithm, there's no API to tell you, what are the upcoming tasks. You would have to make guesses.

*If you ask a more specific question about the specific task that causes this freeze, you may get a more concrete answer.*